# youtube api asks me to access api to my account every one

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I used youtube API to upload videos from my website to my youtube account.
YouTube API asks every time to access API to my account.

Is there any way to ask just one time, and save the account data, and don't ask again for next uploads, please help me

this is my code :

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx';

$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAuthConfig('xxxxxxxx/'.client_secrets.json');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://myWebsiteUrl');

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
   $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
   header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
   exit;
} else{
        $title = 'title';
        $descriptions = 'description';
    }
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
       $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else {
       $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
    try {
      $youtube = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);
      $videoPath = 'video path';

      $snippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
      $snippet->setTitle($title);
      $snippet->setDescription($descriptions);
      $snippet->setCategoryId('22');

      $status = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
      $status->privacyStatus = "public";

      $video = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
      $video->setSnippet($snippet);
      $video->setStatus($status);

      $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

      $client->setDefer(true);

      $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);
      $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $insertRequest, 'video/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

      $status = false;
      $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
      while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
      }

      fclose($handle);
      $client->setDefer(false);

   } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
   } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    die('error');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to set up your [OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens).

From here, you will be able to [Create your project and select API services](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#create_project).

> 1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_).
> 2. The API supports API keys and OAuth 2.0 credentials. Create whichever credentials are appropriate for your project:
>
>    - OAuth 2.0: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a
>        client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can
>        generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts,
>        or installed applications.
>
>      See the [Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) section for more
>        information.
>    - API keys: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API
>        access, quota, and reports.
>
>      See the [Creating API Keys](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_API_Keys) section for information about creating
>        an API key.

Comment: i set up this and i can upload video , but my problem is that youtube asks every time to access API to my account . i want youtube ask once and save my access data for next uploads .